# How to reference a WAF probe by symbolicName rather than as a string

Tags: azure-bicep

I'm trying to deploy an Azure Application Gateway using bicep. I've exported the ARM template and converted it to bicep using VS Code (paste into a .bicep file to have Code automatically convert it).

I'm going through the process of trying to tidy it up and I'm stuck how to reference a Probe from a `backendHttpSettingsCollection` entry. In the code snippet below I've got a backendHttpSettings item `'Be_Settings_HTTPS'` and a probe `'Be_HealthProbe'`, the probe is referenced from the httpSettings using an interpolated string for the Id which gives me an error stating

> "This expression is referencing its own declaration, which is not allowed."

Is it possible to reference this using a symbolic name?

Current bicep snippet

```
resource agw_foo_resource 'Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways@2023-05-01' = {
    name: 'FooAGW'
    location: location
    ...
    properties: {
        backendHttpSettingsCollection: [
            {
                name: 'Be_Settings_HTTPS'
                properties: {
                    port: 443
                    protocol: 'Https'
                    cookieBasedAffinity: 'Disabled'
                    pickHostNameFromBackendAddress: true
                    affinityCookieName: 'ApplicationGatewayAffinity'
                    requestTimeout: 20
                    probe: {
// How can I reference the "Be_HealthProbe" without having to use string interpolation?
                        id: '${applicationGateways_agw_prod_uks_01_name_resource.id}/probes/Be_HealthProbe'
                    }
                }
            }
        probes: [
            {
                name: 'Be_HealthProbe'
                properties: {
                    protocol: 'Https'
                    path: '/'
                    interval: 30
                    timeout: 30
                    unhealthyThreshold: 3
                    pickHostNameFromBackendHttpSettings: true
                    minServers: 0
                    match: {
                        statusCodes: [
                            '200-399'
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
    }
```

Comment: you should be able to use: `resourceId('Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/probes', 'FooAGW', 'Be_HealthProbe')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can refer probe id using '(symolic probe resource name).id' here. because arm template seems not support independently deployment of the probe resource. so the workaround is to use "resourceId". such as below:

```
  resource ApplicationGateway 'Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways@2022-07-01' = {
  name: applicationGatewayNameResource
  location: location
  properties: {
    sku: {
      name: 'Standard_v2'
      tier: 'Standard_v2'
      capacity: 2
    }
    gatewayIPConfigurations: [
      {
        name: 'appGatewayIpConfig'
        properties: {
          subnet: {
            id: subnetRef
          }
        }
      }
    ]
    frontendIPConfigurations: [
      {
        name: 'appGatewayFrontendIP'
        properties: {
          publicIPAddress: {
            id: publicIPRef
          }
        }
      }
    ]
    frontendPorts: [
      {
        name: 'appGatewayFrontendPort'
        properties: {
          port: 80
        }
      }
    ]
    backendAddressPools: [
      {
        name: 'appGatewayBackendPool'
        properties: {
          backendAddresses: [
            {
              ipAddress: AppService.properties.defaultHostName
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
    backendHttpSettingsCollection: [
      {
        name: 'appGatewayBackendHttpSettings'
        properties: {
          port: 80
          hostName: '${siteName}.azurewebsites.net'
          protocol: 'Http'
          cookieBasedAffinity: 'Disabled'
          pickHostNameFromBackendAddress: false
          probeEnabled: true
          probe: {
            id: resourceId('Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/probes/', applicationGatewayNameResource, 'Probe1')
          }
        }
      }
    ]
    httpListeners: [
      {
        name: 'appGatewayHttpListener'
        properties: {
          frontendIPConfiguration: {
            id: resourceId('Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/frontendIPConfigurations/', applicationGatewayNameResource, 'appGatewayFrontendIP')
          }
          frontendPort: {
            id: resourceId('Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/frontendPorts/', applicationGatewayNameResource, 'appGatewayFrontendPort')
          }
          protocol: 'Http'
        }
      }
    ]
    probes: [
      {
        name: 'Probe1'
        properties: {
          protocol: 'Http'
          path: '/'
          interval: 30
          timeout: 10
          unhealthyThreshold: 3
          minServers: 0
          pickHostNameFromBackendHttpSettings: true
        }
      }
    ]
  }
  dependsOn: [
    virtualNetworkName

  ]
}
```

pay attention to `probe1`, and [reference docs](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/16698a1be9c801e7555baa855c53757e860574d1/quickstarts/microsoft.web/webapp-windows-with-privateendpoint-applicationgateway/main.bicep#L99)